# Filter list of distinct values from one column of grouped data in the same order as it shows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset grouped by a few variables and ordered in descending by one of those. I want to get a list of distinct values form one column in the order it appears in the result I have after grouping and ordering by descending.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
set.seed(42)
id    <- seq_len(10)
city  <- sample(c('Miami', 'Seattle', 'Houston', 'Toronto', 'Tokyo', 'Mumbai', 'Austin'), 10, replace = TRUE)
state <- sample(c('ON', 'WA', 'TX', 'MA'), 10, replace = TRUE)
rent  <- sample(800:1900, 10)

data = data.frame(id, city, state, rent)
```

I group by using three columns and sort total rent by descending to get the following result:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id, city, state) %>% 
  summarise(total_rent = sum(rent)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(total_rent))
```

[group_by result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkPRR.jpg)

Now, I want the list of unique city values in the order it appears in the result above.
Eg.

```
Houston
Toronto
Miami
Mumbai
Austin
```

I've tried:

```
  group_by(id, city, state) %>% 
  summarise(total_rent = sum(rent)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(total_rent)) %>% 
  slice_max(1)
```

also `top_n()` and `distinct()`but did not work. I also see `row_number()`could work but I couldn't find a way to make it work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't recreate your data *exactly* for some reason so my output is different but here are a few quick methods that should achieve your desired outcome:

A few edits to your original code gives us a data frame with the proper cities in the proper order:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

id    <- seq_len(10)
city  <- sample(c('Miami', 'Seattle', 'Houston', 'Toronto', 'Tokyo', 'Mumbai', 'Austin'), 10, replace = TRUE)
state <- sample(c('ON', 'WA', 'TX', 'MA'), 10, replace = TRUE)
rent  <- sample(800:1900, 10)

data  <- data.frame(id, city, state, rent)

data %>% 
  group_by(id, city, state) %>% 
  summarise(total_rent = sum(rent)) %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  slice_max(1) %>% 
  arrange(desc(total_rent)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>      id city    state total_rent
#>   <int> <chr>   <chr>      <int>
#> 1     1 Miami   MA          1698
#> 2     6 Toronto WA          1659
#> 3     5 Seattle ON          1420
#> 4     2 Tokyo   TX          1400
#> 5    10 Austin  TX          1098
```

For just the values, the `pull()` / `unique()` combo is quite nice:

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(id, city, state) %>% 
  summarise(total_rent = sum(rent)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(total_rent)) %>% 
  pull(city) %>% 
  unique()
#> [1] "Miami"   "Toronto" "Seattle" "Tokyo"   "Austin"
```

Another possible solution could involve factoring the cities in order after you've arranged them. This is achieved with `library(forecats)`:

```r
library(forcats)
library(magrittr)

data %>% 
  group_by(id, city, state) %>% 
  summarise(total_rent = sum(rent)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(total_rent)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(city = fct_inorder(city)) %$% 
  levels(city) 
#> [1] "Miami"   "Toronto" "Seattle" "Tokyo"   "Austin"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>